# How much do I need to save per month in an interest-bearing account to reach a certain account balance in a certain number of years?

Tags: savings, interest, compound-interest

How do I calculate what my monthly contribution should be to an interest bearing account, knowing how much I'll need to have in the account in a given number of years?

For Example,

I need $8,203.03 in an account in 25 years.  Money in the account garners 4% interest compounded monthly.  My principle investment in the account is $1,000.  What is the formula that can tell me how much will I need to contribute monthly in order to have $8,203.03 in the account in 25 years?

Comment: It's doubtful that you can find any account that will guarantee you a particular interest rate for 25 years, _and_ will let you keep making new deposits at that interest rate for all of those 25 years. If you ignore that (quite significant) practical difficulty, there are [exact mathematical formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest) to find, but they are perhaps more in scope for [Math.SE].

Answer (score 4):

You can re-arrange the future value of an annuity equation to solve for payment (Pmt) needed instead of Future Value (FV):

`FV = Pmt * (((1 + r) ^ n) – 1)/r)`
`Pmt = FV / (((1 + r) ^ n) – 1)/r)`

That will get you payment needed to hit a given future value, but it won't account for the future value of the the starting balance, that should be removed from the desired future value after interest is calculated:

$1,000 at 4% for 25 years with monthly compounding:

`n = number of periods = 12 months x 25 years = 300`
`r = rate per period = .04/12 = 0.003333`
`FV = Future Value = 8203.03`

`FV = PV(1+r)^n`
`FV = 1000 * (1+0.003333)^300`
`FV = 1000 * (1.003333)^300`
`FV = 1000 * 2.7135`
`FV = $2,713.5`

So your $1,000 will be worth $2,713.5 without any additional contribution, remove that from your goal of $8,203.03 and your target from the monthly contributions is: 5,489.53

So to solve for monthly contribution (Pmt) we'll use:

`n = number of periods = 12 months x 25 years = 300`
`r = rate per period = .04/12 = 0.003333`
`FV = Future Value = 5489.53`

`Pmt = FV / (((1 + r) ^ n) – 1)/r)`
`Pmt = 5489.53 / (((1 + .003333) ^ 300) – 1)/.003333)`
`Pmt = 5489.53 / ((1.003333^300) – 1)/.003333)`
`Pmt = 5489.53 / (1.7138)/.003333)`
`Pmt = 5489.53 / 514.19`
`Pmt = 10.68`

You need to contribute $10.68 per month to hit your goal. May be off a few pennies due to rounding.

Even easier would be to leverage an online calculator, [this one seems accurate](https://www.free-online-calculator-use.com/future-value-annuity-payment-calculator.html) and comes up with $10.64. Also could solve in a spreadsheet which would enable you to handle rounding more flexibly.

Answer (score 1):

You need the balance on month N to equal Bf. You make regular contributions of b to the account and get a monthly percentage yield of r (expressed as a real number multiplier. i.e., r = 1.005 is 0.5% monthly). Let B(n) be the balance at the beginning of month n; after the old balance has interest applied and the new contribution is added. Then

```
B(0) = B0
B(1) = B0r + b
B(2) = B0r^2 + br + b
...
B(n) = B0r^n + b(r^(n-1)+ ... + 1)
     = B0r^n + b((r^n)-1)/(r-1)
```

We can solve for b by using B(N) = Bf:

```
Bf = B0r^N + b(r^N-1)/(r-1)
b = (Bf - B0r^N) / [(r^N-1)/(r-1)]
```

Your answer comes out to something like $10.88. This gives you the contribution to reach the goal at the beginning of the last month in the 25-year period; to get the amount at the end, you can re-run the math for n = N + 1 and subtract the contribution from the N+1st month (leaving only the last month's interest). Or, you could rearrange the system and solve for end-of-month balances directly. That might be easier. The key is that understanding the derivation allows you to reason about the details of what your numbers mean.